# How do get attributes with QUERYMAPFEATURES

Tags: mapguide

I retrieved a mapping image of Sheboygan using the following command:
http://127.0.0.1:8008/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?OPERATION=GETMAPIMAGE&VERSION=1.0.0&MAPNAME=Sheboygon&LOCALR=en&MAPDEFINITION=Library%3a%2f%2fSamples%2fSheboygan%2fMaps%2fSheboygan.MapDefinition&FORMAT=PNG&SETDISPLAYDPI=300&SETDISPLAYWIDTH=840&SETDISPLAYHEIGHT=520&USERNAME=Administrator&PASSWORD=admin&SETVIEWCENTERX=-87.73&
SETVIEWCENTERY=43.740&SETVIEWSCALE=5000

Now I want to get the attribute values.  I want to use the following command.  But I first need the session id. How can I obtain the session id? Would the subsequent command be correct?

http://127.0.0.1:8008/mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?
OPERATION=QUERYMAPFEATURES&
VERSION=2.0.0&
SESSION=???&
PERSIST=0&
MAPNAME=Sheboygan&
LAYERNAMES=Parcels&
GEOMETRY=POLYGON((-87.731 43.740, -87.731 43.741, -87.730&43.741, -87.730 43.740, -87.731 43.740,))&
SELECTIONVARIANT=INTERSECTS&
MAXFEATURES=2

Thanks so much,
Gido

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.